# passed parameter to array_multi_sort?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, array-multisort

I have an base array

```
$base =array(
            "A1" =array();
            "A2" =array();
            "A3" =array();
            "A4" =array();
    );
```

and array of condition will use to sort

```
$condition  = array("A1" => "SORT_ASC",
                    "A4" => 'SORT_ASC',
                    "A3" => 'SORT_DESC'
                   );
```

I tried create a function like this to return a array_multi_sort

```
function sort_by_condition($condition) {


    return  array_multisort(
           $base['A1'], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,
           $base['A4'], SORT_ASC,SORT_NUMERIC, 
           $base['A3'], SORT_DESC,SORT_NUMERIC,
           $base['A2'],//default
           );

}
```

But I dont know how can I return something like this?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify your question?

Comment: yes,deceze I have updated the questions.

Comment: If you're calling from in a function, ensure that $A1, $A4, etc are in scope within that function

Comment: yes,the $condition array is the set of $base array.

Comment: `array_multisort()` does not return an array -- it modifies by reference.  This question is low-quality because we do not have a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to  give the proper array keys to array multisort:

```
$ar = array(
       array("10", 11, 100, 100, "a"),
       array(   1,  2, "2",   3,   1)
      );

array_multisort($ar[0], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,
                $ar[1], SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC);
```

This is from the manual but I assume your example would become more like this:

```
 array_multisort( $base['A1'], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,
                  $base['A2'], SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, 
                  etc...
                );
```

I realize you have probably read it a few times but see the examples in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) and try making it work outside the function first. Good-luck! :)